# Fixed element flicker issue when using mousewheel scroll

Tags: jquery, css-position, flicker

I am trying to make the side bar become fixed at the top after scrolling to a certain point.

```
var sidebarTopPos = $('#sidebar').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= sidebarTopPos) {
        $('#sidebar').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#sidebar').css({
            position: 'relative'
        });
    }
});​
```

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HFCM/2/)

The whole thing works fine when I drag the scrollbar down. However, when I try to scroll using the mousewheel, I see the annoying flicker when the side bar changes from "relative" to "fixed" I've tried so many things. Please help.

**EDIT**: Maybe I should have been more clear. The side bar "flickers" only when it crosses the top div

Comment: Seems to work in Firefox as well. In what browser are you seeing the issue?

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle. The "top" div has height such that it doesn't fit exactly into one "mousewheel scroll" then you will see the problem. I'm using Chrome 18

Comment: More specifically, I see the "Test test test..." flicker, as in it moves up a little bit before assuming the correct position

Comment: NOTE: It does work in all other browsers. That's weird... Thank you so much anyways guys!

Comment: @Jay Na welcome to browsers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was having the same issue, it seems to be a bug that occurs when there is too much going on for your browser to handle based on your computer GPU, Memory, CPU, etc..., I was able to fix it by adding the following transform code to the fixed position element, (`transform: translateZ(0);-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`) that forces the browser to use hardware acceleration to access the device’s graphical processing unit (GPU) to make pixels fly. Web applications, on the other hand, run in the context of the browser, which lets the software do most (if not all) of the rendering, resulting in less horsepower for transitions. But the Web has been catching up, and most browser vendors now provide graphical hardware acceleration by means of particular CSS rules.

Using -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); will kick the GPU into action for the CSS transitions, making them smoother (higher FPS).

**Note:** translate3d(0,0,0) does nothing in terms of what you see. it moves the object by 0px in x,y and z axis. It's only a technique to force the hardware acceleration.

```
#sidebar {
    /* MAGIC HAPPENS HERE */
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem at all. When I use the mousewheel, it flickers, when I use the scrollbar, it is absolutely sticky. There is nothing going on in my example. I think it has nothing to do with the GPU. I use Chrome 43.0 (to be precise: I can not use fixed positioning)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question and sure you already found an answer for this, but in case some one have the same issue and need to fix it, just add this css code to the sidebar.

```
#sidebar {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```